# How to populate the dropdown field with value from the input field

Tags: jquery

Below is my dropdown that I'm trying to get the value populated inserted in from the input field.

```
<div id="escDivTable" class="subText">You don't have any values. Set up an escalation value.</div>
<select id ="Options">
<option>Option1</option><option>Option2</option><option>Option3</option></select>
```

This is the input field from where I'm trying to get the value populated into the dropdown.

```
<input class="name" id="nameInput" title="Name should be unique" type ="text" maxlength="100" />
```

Here is the js that gets the input value in a var:

```
name = $(".name").val()
```

I'm stuck at this place, as to how can use this 'name' value automatically popup into the dropdown? I was trying something like this. Obviously dosent work..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
$('.name').change(function() {
name = $(".name").val()
$('#Options').val(name);
});
});
</script>
```

Does anyone have ideas? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    var $opts = $('#Options');
    $('.name').change(function () {
        var name = this.value;
        var len = $opts.find('option').filter(function () {
            return $(this).text() == name
        }).length;
        if (!len) {
            $opts.append('<option value="' + name + '">' + name + '</option>');
        }
        $opts.val(name)
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SpYgM/)